# Script for selecting sheets using control

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have in a spreadsheet, a MENU with buttons linked to other sheets.
Since I have many sheets, I want that when selecting a button it is the same for a group of those sheets.

Ex: btn "Enter approved teachers", there are 4 sheets that are to enter that data, each one corresponds to a different area.

That when I click on this button, I skip a "popup" that shows me a list of that sheets and lets me select it with an "OK".

The part of selecting the sheet with a script is easy to do with a youtube tutorial, but the control of sheets and selection I can not find anywhere.

I haven't been able to try anything, as I don't have experience coding in Apps Script or Js.

Comment: Questions just post code requirements aren't a good fit for this site. As you mention that you aren't able to try anything, please start by spending some time learning the basics of JavaScript and Google Apps Script. Once to are able to write code, if you still need help, please comeback and show what you have tried.

Comment: Dear, I am learning about fundamentals, but it takes time. And this is a task to improve an interactive project. Maybe for you to solve it is 5 minutes and you want to give me a learning lesson, me learning to program in my free time. Thank you.

Comment: If you are looking for learning lessons try asking for guidance in [cseducators.se]. See [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421418/1595451) to a question on [meta] asking for a learning resource.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is close to what you are looking for:

This a dialog I use for selecting which files I wish to backup from my spreadsheets.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
        input {margin: 2px 5px 2px 0;}
    #btn3,#btn4{display:none}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="scr" name="script" size="60" placeholder="Enter Apps Script Id" onchange="getFileNames();" />
        <br /><input type="text" id="fldr" name="folder" size="60" placeholder="Enter Backup Folder Id" />
        <div id="shts"></div>
    <br /><input type="button" value="0" onClick="unCheckAll();" size="15" id="btn3" />
    <input type="button" value="1" onClick="checkAll();"size="15" id="btn4"/>
        <br /><input type="checkbox" id="files" name="saveFiles" checked /><label for="files">Save Files</label>
        <br /><input type="checkbox" id="json" name="saveJson" checked /><label for="json">Save JSON</label>
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="backupFiles();" />
    </form>
        <script>
      function getFileNames() {
        const scriptid = document.getElementById("scr").value;
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((names) => {
          document.getElementById('btn3').style.display = "inline";
          document.getElementById('btn4').style.display = "inline";
          names.forEach((name,i) => {
           let br = document.createElement("br"); 
           let cb = document.createElement("input");
           cb.type = "checkbox";
           cb.id = `cb${i}`;
           cb.name = `cb${i}`;
           cb.className = "cbx";
           cb.value = `${name}`;
           cb.checked = true;
           let lbl = document.createElement("label");
           lbl.htmlFor = `cb${i}`;
           lbl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${name}`));
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(cb);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(lbl);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(br);
          });
        })
        .getAllFileNames({scriptId:scriptid}); 
      }
      function unCheckAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length);
        for(let i =0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = false;
        }
      }
      function checkAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length)
        for(let i = 0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = true; 
        }
      }
      function backupFiles() {
        console.log('backupFiles');
        sObj = {};
        sObj.script = document.getElementById('scr').value;
        sObj.folder = document.getElementById('fldr').value;
        sObj.saveJson = document.getElementById('json').checked?'on':'';
        sObj.saveFiles = document.getElementById('files').checked?'on':'';
        sObj.selected = [];
        console.log("1");
        const cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        let selected = [];
        for(let i = 0;i<cbs.length; i++) {
          let cb = cbs[i];
          if(cb.checked) {
            sObj.selected.push(cb.value)
          } 
        }
        console.log("2");
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){google.script.host.close();})
        .scriptFilesBackup(sObj);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(sObj));
      }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what the dialog looks like:

[image]

Comment: Grateful for the estimated answer!!, But what I try to do is simpler I think. Basically, I want you to click a button. I see a "modal" pop up with a drop down list and that each of the options are sheets of the book. Selecting the option activates that sheet and displays it.